# Show fragments above another fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Basically, what I want to do is:

[image: Fragments lifecycle]

  1.- I have two fragments "outside" the activity.

  2.- Now there could be two possibilities, fragment 1 or fragment must be shown with a slide up animation.

  3.- Fragment 1 is always above fragment 2 when both are on screen.

  4.- Any of the fragments can hide, placing correctly the showing one at the botton of the screen.

I am a little bit lost with layout design. I have tried

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I even show both of them at the same time. Even using different fragmenttransactions for each fragment. Using, `android:layout_above` doesn't work.

What is the simplest way to develop this design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Animate the linearLayout. And as per your requirement change the visiblity of framelayout(gone/visible)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using two FrameLayouts for FragmentA would help for the two scenarios.

1. When it is the only one visible you can use 
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
2. When it is on top of FrameLayout holding FragmentB, you can use
   android:layout_above="@+id/fragment2"

Then play with the "visibilities" of these based on your scenarios.